# How can i find all roots for a function using Newton Rapshon method in Scilab?

Tags: function, scilab

I need to find all roots for this function f(x)=-2x^4+x^3-2x+3 in given interval [-1.5 ; 1.5] with accuracy being <0.0001. Then i have to plot the relative mistakes.
So i got this code but it's not working.

```
deff('y=f(x)','y=-2x^4+x^3-2x+3')
a=input("Enter value of interval a:")
b=input("Enter value of interval b:")
n=input("Enter the number of iteration n:")
x0=(a+b)/2
for i=1:n
    disp([i,x0])
    x1=x0-f(x0)/z(x0)
    if abs(x1-x0)<0.00001 then
        disp("We get required accuracy")
        break;
    end
    x0=x1
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 pbs in your code;

- The definition of f function must be

  deff('y=f(x)','y=-2*x^4+x^3-2*x+3')
- You did not define the z function in your code. It should compute the derivative of f at x

  deff('y=z(x)','y=-8*x^3+3*x^2-2')

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of the existence of a function already developed in Scilab, which can be used to find the roots of equations, I believe so. In python we can use **scipy.optimize.newton** (Among others like **bisect**, **toms748** etc). For comparison we have an implementation of a Newton-Rapshon algorithm. You can use the logic developed in this algorithm, and rewrite a scilab version.

## Python

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import newton, bisect, toms748
from scipy.misc import derivative

# Function f(x), where x* in f(x = x*) = 0
def f(x):
  return -2*np.power(x,4)+np.power(x,3)-2*x+3

intervalo_x = np.linspace(-1.5,1.5,1000)
tol = 1E-04
#x_chute_inicial = np.median(intervalo_x)
x_chute_inicial = 10
N0 = 50

#########################
# scipy.optimize.newton #
#########################
raiz = newton(func = f , x0 = x_chute_inicial, fprime = None, tol = 1.48e-08, maxiter = N0, fprime2 = None, x1 = None, rtol = 0.0, 
              full_output = False, disp = True)
print('Implementation of scipy.optimize.newton')
print(f'raiz = {raiz} | f(raiz) = {f(raiz)}')
print(f'\n')

############################
# Newton-Rapshon algorithm #
############################
erro_absoluto = np.zeros(N0)
erro_relativo = np.zeros(N0)
iteracoes     = np.zeros(N0)

i = 1
while i<=N0:
    x = x_chute_inicial - (f(x_chute_inicial)/derivative(f,x0=x_chute_inicial,dx=tol,n=1)) # Root
    erro_abs = np.abs(x-x_chute_inicial) # Absolute error
    if erro_abs<tol:
      print('Implementation of the Newton-Rapshon algorithm')
      print(f"x = {x}\n"
              f"Number of iterations: {i}\n"
              f"Absolute error: {erro_abs}\n"
              f"Relative error: {np.abs((x-x_chute_inicial)/x_chute_inicial)}\n"
              f"f({x}) = {f(x)}")
      break
    erro_relativo[i] = np.abs((x-x_chute_inicial)/x_chute_inicial)
    erro_absoluto[i] = np.abs(x-x_chute_inicial)
    iteracoes[i] = i
    i = i + 1
    x_chute_inicial = x

###########
# graphic #
###########
plt.figure(figsize = (21,6))
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.plot(intervalo_x,f(intervalo_x),'b-')
plt.title(r'f(x) = $-2x^{4}+x^{3}-2x+3$')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid(lw = 0.95,color = 'm',linestyle = '--')

plt.subplot(1,3,2)
plt.plot(iteracoes,erro_relativo,'y*')
plt.title('relative error')
plt.xlabel('number of iterations i')
plt.ylabel('relative error')
plt.grid(lw = 0.95,color = 'g',linestyle = '--')

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.plot(iteracoes,erro_absoluto,'g^')
plt.title('absolute error')
plt.xlabel('number of iterations i')
plt.ylabel('absolute error')
plt.grid(lw = 0.95,color = 'y',linestyle = '--')
```

The roots of this equation, contained in the closed interval [-1.5,1.5] are approximately **x0 = -1.1693** and **x1 = 1.0**. Finally below we have the graphs of f(x) by x, absolute error by iterations and relative error by interactions.

[Figure generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LngAY.png)